# real time Chat module in dynamic web application

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

i developed matrimonial website using struts2, mysql, jquery technologies.
now i want to  include chat module in my application, can some tell me how to achieve it.
i goggled on it and find chatting server needed along with some library files, and it can be done using ajax chat also.

**could any one tell me or give me link with example to develop chatting application in struts2, i want to implement it just like in the facebook**

Thanks in advance

Comment: let us have a demo of the site please .. :)

Comment: you want to develop your own chat server or you are looking for third party solution

Comment: Want to develop own chat server @UmeshAwasthi

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi can u suggest some of the third party solution how i can use it ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using HTML5. If so you can use websockets with help of web workers and can create chat app which runs in your web page as a seperates component.Gmail is using the same concepts for the chat app. But this can be done using HTML5. As of now IE 8 is suppoterd with HTML5.Only chrome,safari and mozilla are supported with HTML5.

Comment: HTML is not still fully supported by all browsers. Bad idea for a website , which should reach maximum potential audience

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are looking for transport solution, as much realtime as possible.
WebSockets are not widely supported, but they are highly preferable for such applications.

So you might want to have a look into Socket.IO that implements WebSockets with failover into longpoll if WebSockets are not available.

For server side, this will be very different from Web application development that you get use to developing existing application.

So you have to read some information regarding overall idea of developing realtime networking applications.
In meantime you have to choose server side language / technology.
Because you need chat, and it might be lots of users, you might better to have a look in more low level languages, like .Net, Java, C++, Node.js, and others. PHP here wont be good solution, due to old approach for development web applications it turn to be horrible idevelopment of realtime networking applications.

For Java, you might want to have a look [jWebSockets](http://jwebsocket.org/), and for Data Protocol, if you want use JSON which I would do, check [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Comment: i want to use java can u provide some link or info on how to achieve it using java. @Maksims Mihejevs

Comment: Added in the end of the answer some links.

Comment: i saw it and go through that but how to include it to my jsp and struts2